# Generating slides automatically in Beamer

Tags: beamer

In `Beamer`, we need to create each slide separately. Is it possible to generate those slides automatically (just like pages an `article` type document does)?

Somewhat related: I occasionally see some bits are going beyond the bottom of a slide (texts or anything). Creating slides automatically, I hope, will remove this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Beamer, this corresponds to the `allowframebreak` option:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{A way too long frame that will break, eventually}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
    ...
\end{frame}
```

With `\framebreak` you can insert a forced break onto the next slide (similar to `\newpage` in article).

The details are described in §8.1 of the [Beamer user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

However, in my opinion, this option should be used with care! An automatic splitting of the content makes only sense, if the content itself is automatically generated. Bibliographies are an obvious example. I strongly suggest to also read the respective words of warnings from the Beamer user guide (p61):

> **The use of this option is evil**. In a (good) presentation you prepare each slide carefully and think twice before putting something on a certain slide rather than on some different slide. Using the allowframebreaks option invites the creation of horrible, endless presentations that resemble more a “paper projected on the wall” than a presentation. Nevertheless, the option does have its uses. Most noticeably, it can be convenient for automatically splitting bibliographies or long equations.